# Google Compute Engine Linux Password (for xrdp)

Tags: google-compute-engine

How I can find the password for my Linux VM 
Is there no option but to create a new user ?
I'm dropping VNC because it's slow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, SSH login into your linux VM takes place via **SSH key file**, which is uploaded into the VM prior to connection (for instance, when you connect using the SSH button / applet in the Developers Console) due to the fact that clear-text passwords, and challenge-response authentication are disabled.

In order to connect using a regular password, **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** needs to be editted, changing the following lines:

1 - ChallengeResponseAuthentication no -> change to yes

2 - PasswordAuthentication no -> change to yes

After a service restart (sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart) you ought to be able to log in using your username and password. If your username didn't get a password at deployment time, you can establish one connecting with the VM via the Console's SSH, and using the command:

$sudo passwd  (you can leave the username out if it's the one your using at the time)

Comment: but where is the password?

Comment: where is the password?

Comment: If the deployment hasn't set a password for your user, connect to your machine via the Console's built-in key file-authorized SSH, and establish a new password:
$ sudo passwd (for your current user) or,
$ sudo password <username> (for any other username)
As long as you modified the SSH server's config as stated above, you should be set.